# What does this mean? It's a quote by Nietzsche

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What does this mean: "haben und mehrwollhaben" ? I could not find it anywhere, dictionary nor google.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please, quote the exact passage. *Mehrwollhaben* is not a German verb, not even a newly constructed one in accordance with construction rules. I would be very surprised if Nietzsche had written it. Maybe he wrote *mehr haben wollen* (to want to have more), but these are three distinct words, not one.

Comment: Your unnamed source butchered the German (see [here](https://www.schwabeonline.ch/schwabe-xaveropp/elibrary/start.xav?start=%2F%2F*%5B%40#__elibrary__%2F%2F*%5B%40attr_id%3D%27verw.mehrhabenwollen%27%5D__1610473996238)).

Comment: @DavidVogt, this cannot be the source. Neither Nietzsche nor the phrase *haben und mehrwollhaben* is mentioned anywhere. Moreover, the linked article is about the noun *Mehrhabenwollen*, whereas the question is about a (non existing verb) *mehrwollhaben*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I wanted to show is that *mehrwollhaben* is incorrect by linking an article using the correct term.

Comment: @DavidVogt, oh, I missed this intention of you. Is that why you used *butchered*? I looked it up and my dictionary said *abschlachten*. So, I was confused what you were supposed to say with that. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The made-up word "mehrwollhaben" seems to be a mistaken quote by the philosopher [Alasdair MacIntyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alasdair_MacIntyre) in his book [After Virtue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Virtue). MacIntyre claims that Nietzsche translated the philosophical concept of [Pleonexia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonexia) as "haben und mehrwollhaben".

But since this word doesn't make sense in German, we can assume MacIntyre meant to refer to the far more logical "mehrhabenwollen". We can assume that Nietzsche used this version, being "haben und mehrhabenwollen", "to have and to (always) want to have more".

[Pleonexia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonexia) is a philosophical concept that Wikipedia says

> is strictly defined as "the insatiable desire to have what rightfully belongs to others", suggesting what Ritenbaugh describes as "ruthless self-seeking and an arrogant assumption that others and things exist for one's own benefit".

Comment: But MacIntyre's claim that Nietzsche used *mehrwollhaben* is wrong. It's obviously *Mehrhabenwollen* (or, of course, *mehr haben wollen*).

Comment: Better now? - Besser so?

Comment: It looks more like Nietzsche wrote "haben und mehr haben wollen", not "mehrhabenwollen".

Comment: @mtwde At least "Mehrhabenwollen" seems to be an established term in philosophical discourse, see for example [here](https://www.swr.de/-/id=15402852/property=download/nid=660374/16d7b7q/swr2-wissen-20150604.pdf), [here](http://www.latein-weierhof.de/philosophie_stroh.htm) or [here](http://wiki.vonwolkenstein.de/doku.php?id=pleonexie).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Shouldn't "Mehrhabenwollen" always be capitalized in this case? However this is about Nietzsche, I think one source for the quote is [this](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/60360/60360-h/60360-h.htm), [webcache link](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FjvIxIRef6kJ:https://www.gutenberg.org/files/60360/60360-h/60360-h.htm+&cd=5&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de) By the way, another spelling used in this text is "Mehr-haben-wollen".

Comment: @mtwde, thanks for the link. It demonstrates very nicely the nonsense that is often spouted when quoting. Nietzsche wrote: *"Haben und haben wollen, **Wachstum** mit einem Wort [...]"* But instead of simply referring to *Wachstum*, people quote the much longer verb phrase and even do so incorrectly.

Comment: Quotation from MacIntyre's book: "Nietzsche translated *pleonexia* with insight as well as precision: *haben und mehrwollhaben*."

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Nietzsche wrote "**Haben und mehr haben wollen**, Wachstum mit einem Wort – das ist das Leben selber."